# How Do I Mirror Knife Tool?

Tags: modeling, mirror

In blender cycles I am trying to mirror the knife tool but it won't work. I have tried mirroring the knife tool using the mirror modifier and using mesh options as well to mirror.

Comment: What do you mean by "mirror knife tool"? You can cut all through the mesh with Knife tool (`K`) while `Z` pressed (see on the bottom of 3D View for parameters) and orthographic mode active for expected results if that's what you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

hope you are working on the mesh which is already mirrored so after applying knife it eidt mode it should mirrored.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a symmetric mesh you can use go to the tool shelf at the options tab and select the *x mirror* option.

Comment: hm, this does not work in blender 2.82alpha

Comment: That will not work. You could use a Mirror Modifier on the mesh, if it is symmetrical.