# A Possible Answer for "How Do I Mirror Knife Tool"

Tags: modeling, mirror

Working on mesh modified with mirror modifier. Attempted a knife cut. Was not reflected on the mirror. Looked around and came across what looked like my problem on Stack Exchange ([How Do I Mirror Knife Tool?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40831/how-do-i-mirror-knife-tool)), but no suitable answer.

Looked around more on blender, and noticed in the mirror-modifier panel, at the top of the panel, is a push-button labeled "On Cage". When I selected it, my knife cut was mirrored.

I would like to let others know, in case this is a suitable answer for some.

Since I have no reputation, I am unable to answer or comment on the question. This was the only method I could think of to answer.

Comment: Hi :). Thanks for stopping by and sharing a solution ;). (btw knife cuts are always mirrored, it's just the mirrored side doesn't *display* the new edges)

Comment: Hi Jachym. Thanks for that clarification. Yes, experimenting on a cube agrees with what you said. When I grab and move the edge, the mirrored portion also moves.